# JaCoCo inner branches coverage

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I have code snipped:

```java
@Override
public Object put(String key, Object value) {
    checkNotNull(key);
    return map.put(key, value);
}

public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
}
```

Method `put` have no branches, and `checkNotNull` precondition have 2. 
If I will invoke `put("key", new Object());` I will get full coverage of branches. But semantically `put` have 2 branches - one in method itself and 2 nested.

It is possible to retrieve 'real' branch coverage with all inner branches?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems. The jacoco report shows 50% branch coverage (see "MyClass" or "checkNotNull()"). Please note that a method with complexity 1 has no branch coverage. No matter if the method is called ("put") or not ("notCalled").

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank for response. Yes, I agree that in this case it will work, but if I will have 2 methods `put(String, Object)` and `put2(String, Object)` and the test where I will check only `put(null, new Object())` and `put2("string", new Object())` then coverage will be 100%, but each method will be covered only by 1 test case